# How to solve an 'Attribute error' in classes for instance attributes?

Tags: python-3.x, class, tkinter, turtle-graphics, attributeerror

My homework needs to write functions in two classes(Person and World) and I'm pretty sure my code is correct. However,

> "AttributeError: 'World' object has no attribute 'destination'"

keeps showing up when self.destination only exist in Person class.

It seems like the word 'self' is now referring to World class and I cannot figure out why.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, world_size):
        self.world_size = world_size
        self.radius = 7
        self.location = turtle.position()#this cause attribute error
        self.destination = self._get_random_location()#and this causes too

    #moves person towards the destination
    def move(self):
        turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(self.destination))
        turtle.forward(self.radius/2)
```

Should I be replacing the 'self' with other words for Person class? If so, how could I do it?

```
class World:
    def __init__(self, width, height, n):
        self.size = (width, height)
        self.hours = 0
        self.people = []
        self.add_person()

    #everything involve of Person class in World class
    #add a person to the list
    def add_person(self):
        person = Person(1)
        self.people.append(person)

    def simulate(self):
        self.hours += 1
        Person.update(self)

    def draw(self):
        p = Person(self)
        p.draw()
```

**

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\ \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1702, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\ \AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 746, in callit
    func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\VIRUS_PART_A.py", line 261, in __animation_loop
    self.tick()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\VIRUS_PART_A.py", line 216, in next_turn
    self.world.simulate()
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\VIRUS_PART_A.py", line 124, in simulate
    Person.update(self)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\VIRUS_PART_A.py", line 71, in update
    Person.move(self)
  File "C:\Users\Desktop\VIRUS_PART_A.py", line 79, in move
    turtle.setheading(turtle.towards(self.destination))
AttributeError: 'World' object has no attribute 'destination'
```

**

Comment: Show us your `World` class definition

Comment: The issues seem to be with `def simulate` and `def draw`; when you say update all people for simulate, does this mean update each person within `self.people`? your People constructor seems to be taking world size, but you are passing a world object in `draw`, so can you explain what the desired behaviour is here too?

Comment: can you also include the full traceback of the error?

Comment: the 'update all people' just means calling the update method in Person class and self.people is a list that stores a person's information from Person class and for the world object, if I just use'Person.draw(self)' to call draw in Person, "AttributeError: 'World' object has no attribute 'radius'" this will comes up as I need to use self.radius to create a dot.

Comment: if you have `radius` in `Person` and you have `Person` in `World` as `self.people[0]` then in `World` you can't use `self.radius` but `self.people[0].radius`

Comment: instead of `p = Person(self)` and `p.draw()` you should use `self.people[0].draw()` or better loop `for item in self.people: item.draw()`

Comment: show all methods in `Person` - your error shows problem in `Person.move`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have Person on list `self.people` so you should use this list in loop

```
def simulate(self):
    self.hours += 1
    for item in self.people:
        item.update(self)

def draw(self):
    for item in self.people:
        item.draw()
```

Probably in `Person` you use `Person.move()` but you should use `self.move()` or something similar.

Comment: But can I ask how did python know 'item.update(self)' is calling method in Person class?

Comment: `item` is from list `self.people` and in `add_person()` you create `Person()` and add it to `self.people` - so `item` has to be `Person`. You can check it with `print(  type(item) )`